# using getBuildConfigFields().getAt() in build.gradle returns null

Tags: android, build.gradle

In my android build.gradle file, I want to use a build config field value that is set in each flavor for my package name suffix.

Say my package is "com.my.app", and my config field's name is "myConfigFieldName".

I try to do:

```
applicationIdSuffix "." + getBuildConfigFields().getAt("myConfigFieldName")
```

And after running the build, my package is "com.my.app.null", when I expected something like "com.my.app.flavorA"

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this is a way to append the flavor name onto the app package.
I also check that the release type is release, so I will be able to switch between flavors during dev without installing more and more apps

```
buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }

        //append flavor name to the package name in release builds
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            if(variant.buildType.name.equals('release')) {
                variant.productFlavors.each() { flavor ->
                    variant.mergedFlavor.applicationId = variant.mergedFlavor.applicationId + '.' + flavor.name
                }
            }
        }
    }
```